# Create associative array and sum value with the same key

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using symfony, and am trying to pass data to twig template to render a plot.

I have entity Points, it has properties: `$datetime` and `$points`

```
foreach($points as $p)
  {
     $unixTime = round(strtotime($p->getDateTime())/100, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN)*100000;
     $a[$unixTime] += $p->getPoints();
  }
```

The idea is to make associative array with key as date in Unix format and value as sum of points received.

When pass `$a` var to twig template and run the code I always receive

> Notice: Undefined offset: #############
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException

What will be the best option to avoid it?

Comment: change $a[$unixTime] += $p->getPoints(); to $a[$unixTime][] = $p->getPoints();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($points as $p){
     $unixTime = round(strtotime($p->getDateTime())/100, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN)*100000;

     if (isset($a[$unixTime])){
        $a[$unixTime] += $p->getPoints();
     } else {
        $a[$unixTime] = $p->getPoints();
     }

  }
```